ProtectedBrowserStorage is throwing an error for Key Not Found in Key Ring
This is way out of my knowledge base.  I have a .Net 8 Blazor web server app that runs in an Azure App Service.  I have to access an external api using an Oath token.  I store that token (and the refresh token) in the local storage.  I have one user that just started getting an error.  When the code tries to get the token from local storage it throws an error "The Key {guid here} was not found in the key ring."

Everything I found about this error relates so IIS but this is an Azure App Service.
Prior to this he was using the app just fine.  I had him clear his cache as well as go into the external api and revoke any tokens to force the app to get a fresh one.  Didn't fix the problem.
Here's the relevent part of the code.  I am injecting private ProtectedLocalStorage LocalStorage in the constructor.
public async Task GetBearerTokenAsync(string? code)
{
    var adobeToken = string.Empty;
    var baseURI = NavManager.BaseUri.Trim('/');
    try
    {
        adobeToken = (await LocalStorage.GetAsync<string>("token").ConfigureAwait(false)).Value;
        if (adobeToken == null)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation($"GET Token for {Globals.UserEmail} was null.");
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
       Logger.LogError(ex.Message);
        throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex);
    }

It's throwing the error at LocalStorage.GetAsync<string>("token").  No one else is impacted!  ugh.
I'm sure I'm missing some info so tell me what else you need and I'll update the question.

If this is only effecting one user, start by checking the privacy and security on the user's browser.  Also, in their browser dev window check the Application or Storage Tab (depending on the browser) and see if any data you are putting in local storage is being stored correctly.  They probably had an update that changed some security settings.

I didn't realize initially that this also involved a couple of virtual desktops.  Here is our theory: We think the VDs share the same user "state". One VD is one or more versions behind the other due to a rolling update strategy.  The VD that is behind is the one that can't access the key ring.  We think that something in the Windows cryptography changed between versions and one can't decrypt what was encrypted by the other.  We'll know for sure once all updates are rolled out but, in the meantime, I'll close this post.
